# How to disable double-click side button to install?

Tags: iphone, ios

On iPhone 13, how can I disable the "Double-click side button to install" bs in the app store?

I want to download free apps mainly, and I would have hoped for a minimal barrier. To be honest, I don't even want it to ask me my password. I especially don't want to have to perform this impossible contortion every time; how can I replace it with a button at the bottom of the screen like the older iPhones I've used have had?

Comment: It's not "BS;" it's by *design. By having a process that forces you to purchase even free apps, you build in a layer of security you completely lose with your method.

Comment: @allan Why is double-tapping the power button more secure than tapping a button on the screen?

Comment: Because it's inconvenient by design.  There is no doubt that you intended to install the software.

Comment: Trouble it is not just inconvieient it is difficult to do - I often have to try several times - whilst iPhone SE is a nice big button that just need yout thumb print.

Comment: The basic issue here is that older phones had touch Id which required an action to authenticate whilst newer use FaceID which authenticates without you taking an action. Thus Apple had to add something to stop automatic unwanted downloads.

Comment: @mmmmmm the action they could have required could have been to touch the bottom of the phone with your thumb... e.g. an on-screen button. Basically the same as touch ID. Instead they did something which seems no more secure but certainly more impossible?

Comment: @theonlygusti I agree